# SOAP getBody method vs writeTo

Tags: java, soap

I am trying to create a soapMessage to later pass into the following code snippet:

```
SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
SOAPConnection connection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
SOAPMessage response = connection.call(message, url);
```

However, I am receiving a empty (null) response: [SOAP-ENV:Body: null].

When I execute the following (before the connection call):

```
System.out.println(message.getSOAPBody());
message.writeTo(System.out);
```

I get two different responses when they should be the same, correct?

First system print ln gives me [SOAP-ENV:Body: null], while the other actually gives me the soap message I created (writeTo).

Any ideas why?

Full code:

```
MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
SOAPMessage message = factory.createMessage();
SOAPEnvelope envelope = message.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
SOAPElement tvl = envelope.addAttribute(new QName("xmlns:tvl"), "http://some.url.com/");
SOAPBody body = message.getSOAPBody();
QName bodyText = new QName("tvl:searchAirings");
SOAPBodyElement bodyElement = body.addBodyElement(bodyText); 
QName fromTag = new QName("from");
SOAPElement from = bodyElement.addChildElement(fromTag);
from.setValue("2012-11-02T14:00:00-4:00");

QName toTag = new QName("to");
SOAPElement to = bodyElement.addChildElement(toTag);
to.setValue("2012-11-02T18:00:00-4:00");

QName networkTag = new QName("network");
SOAPElement network = bodyElement.addChildElement(networkTag);
network.setAttribute("id", "n501");
network.setAttribute("language", "es");

System.out.println(message.getSOAPBody());
message.writeTo(System.out);
```

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println(message.getSOAPBody());` => This should just print the Body of the SOAP Envelope.

`message.writeTo(System.out);` => This should print complete SOAP Message i.e the Envelope,Header and Body.

Comment: The result of calling message.getSoapBody() is null, while the result (of the same SOAPMessage) is the complete SOAPMessage; which is expected. 

I am wondering why the getSOAPBody() doesn't print the body correctly.

Comment: Which implementation are you using?

Comment: I am seeing the same issue as @user1792298 and I am using the implementation bundled with JDK6.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this by writing the response to ByteArrayOutputStream

```
SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection
        .call(createSOAPRequest(), url);

ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
soapResponse.writeTo(byteOutStream);
String res = new String(byteOutStream.toByteArray());
System.out.println("Response \n"+res);
```